# How parse char character in java

Tags: java

```
My file
ABABCCC
```

My java code:

```
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("My file"));

        StringTokenizer sr = new StringTokenizer(br.readLine());
        char[] problem = null;
        int i = 0;
        while(sr.hasMoreTokens())
        {
            problem[i] = sr.nextToken();
            i++;
        }
```

desired output:

```
problem[0] = 'A'
problem[1] = 'B'
and so on
```

Please help me in this and provide me a good method for this.

Comment: All you need is the `toCharArray` method in `String`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using [`StringTokenizer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html), from the Javadoc -

> `StringTokenizer` is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of `String` or the `java.util.regex` package instead.

If I understand what you're trying to do, here's one way to do it with a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) and [`String.toCharArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) -

```
Scanner sc;
char[] problem = null;
try {
    sc = new Scanner(new File("My file"));
    if (sc.hasNext()) {
        problem = sc.next().toCharArray();
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(problem));
```

Comment: what if input contains 1234 instead of ABA

Comment: Then you'd get {'1','2','3','4'}

Comment: then how i could get an array same as it was in the case of character please help

Comment: That is the same. An array of characters.

Comment: if i want an integer array

Comment: An integer array from a String? You can use scanner.nextInt() to get 1234 (a single int). Or you can iterate the character array above and copy it to an array of int (you'll need to parse each character to an int).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `StringTokenizer` for this data. Just read the data from the file into a `String` and convert it to a `char` array.

```
String line = br.readLine();
char[] problem = line.toCharArray();
```

You'd only need a loop to read this data if you had multiple lines in your file, or if you had multiple tokens to parse.

Answer (score 2):

StingTokenizer doesn't split up a line by chars it will do it by tokens which is equivalent to words in a sentence. [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html) is an example usage of that class.

You can store the entire line into a string and then convert that into the char array you have setup.

```
String fileInput = br.readLine();
char[] problem = fileInput.toCharArray();
```